# Who won this Game?

Tags: full-house

We do not know who finally won this hand. Could you help us?
[image: This was the hand]

Answer (score 0):

It's a split pot, both players have 2 pair, Kings and Tens, 8 kicker.

Answer (score 0):

Both players have the exact same hand, so it’s a pot split.

To determine who won, you need to choose the 5 best cards among the 7 possible cards for each player (2 from their hole cards, 5 from the community cards)

left player has a pair of tens made from the ten in his hole cards and the ten in the community cards, and a pair of kings from the community cards.
they then need to choose the best card from the remaining cards that they didn’t use to make a pair, which is the 8 in the community cards.

Right player has the exact same two pairs has left player (same explanation). 
This player also has an 8 in his hole cards, but this card cannot be used to make a pair with the other 8 because 6 cards would have to be used (you have to use 5 cards maximum)
So this player just has to choose the remaining best card, which is either their own 8 or the community’s 8.

The kickers in this example (7 for the left player, 8 for the right player) are not relevant, as the community cards provide a better card for the 5th card they have to choose.